# How to pass arguments to a callback function in express?

Tags: express, routes, callback

I'm using express middleware with NodeJS. I organized my routes with no callbacks, but for some of them it's better to mutualize functions, so I began to write some callbacks.

I have for example this function (I don't put the whole code, it's useless for my question here):

```
async function verification(req, res, next) {
```

And I use it like this in the route part:

```
router.post('/item/:id/dosomething',
  verification,
  async (req, res) => {
```

Everything works well, but if I want to continue using callbacks (sometimes it's a good solution to have a clean and efficient code), I'll have to pass some arguments to the function. Of course I tried this, and it didn't work:

```
router.post('/item/:id/dosomething',
  verification(arg1, arg2),
  async (req, res) => {
```

I searched on StackOverflow answers for "pass arguments to a callback function" but the few that could be interesting talked about a wrapping function, which I don't think I can implement in my case.

If anybody could give me a hand, that would be great. Thanks :)

---

Here is a snippet of how a `next` worked without writing it in the call (look at the `verif`):

**The callback:**

```
async function verif(req, res, next) {
  let rows;
  const {
    id
  } = req.params;
  ({ rows } = await db.query(`XXX`))
  if (rows.length === 1) {
    return next();
  } else {
    retour(req, res, 500, "No can do.");
  }
```

**Where it's called:**

```
router.post('/mymusic/:id/addElements',
  droits.verifRightsCB.bind(undefined, 'music', 'addInMyMusic'),
  verif,
  async (req, res) => {...
```

The last part of the route (`async (req, res) =>`) is only executed when the `next()` condition is fulfilled in the `verif`, although I didn't pass any argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function verification(arg1, arg2, req, res, next) {...}
router.post('/item/:id/dosomething',
  verification.bind(undefined, arg1, arg2),
  (req, res) => {...}
```

(The functions need not be `async`.)

Note that the `router.post` statement is executed during server start-up, not per request. Therefore you cannot write something like

```js
router.post('/item/:id/dosomething',
  verification.bind(undefined, arg1, req.params.arg),
  (req, res) => {...}
```

because there is no `req` during server start-up. Instead, you may write

```js
router.post('/item/:id/dosomething',
  (req, res, next) => verification(arg1, req.params.arg, req, res, next),
  (req, res) => {...}
```

The `verification` function can then

- call `next()` after successful verification to invoke the other middleware function (`(req, res) => {...}`)
- or call `next(err)` after a verification error in order to skip the other middleware function and report the error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand why these functions need not to be `async`. I have `await` in each of them, so I have to put `async`.

Comment: Async functions are functions that return a Promise. Express middleware functions do not return anything, so it does not matter whether you declare them as async. Middleware functions call `next()` in order to pass control to the next middleware function, that's their way of implementing asynchronousness.

Comment: OK I understood. I unselected this answer because it appears I can't use the "req" inside the call. I would have liked to be able to write `verification.bind(undefined, arg1, req.params.arg)`.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 You cannot use `req` inside `router.post`, because there is no `req` at that point in time. See my augmented answer.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much, everything is very clear. Strangely, I could use `next` before without putting `(req, res,next)` before the callback call.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 How could you use `next` before? Can you paste a code snippet?

Comment: Sorry for the late, I was on holidays. I posted some lines of my code to show you how it worked. I thought it was normal!

Comment: The middleware `verif` is equivalent to the middleware `(req, res, next) => verif(req, res, next)`. But filling the extra arguments `arg1` and `args2` of the `verification` function requires the long version `(req, res, next) => verification(arg1, req.params.arg, req, res, next)`.